# How to make a robots.txt on Django

Tags: django, sitemap, robots.txt

I've seen other answers here, but they aren't really helpful, which is why I am asking. I tried the django-robots framework as well, but it gives me an error when i just put 'robots' in my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'index.apps.IndexConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
]
```

Comment: Robots.txt has nothing related to `INSTALLED_APPS`. About robots.txt you should use your webserver to serve it, nginx or apache or any webserver which you use to deploy your Django app on production server

Answer (score 7):

You can use simply use a `TemplateView`

## template: robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /accounts/
```

## urls.py

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type='text/plain')),
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django has nothing to do with your robots.txt file. This file is used as a reference by the search crawlers while going through your website. By default, all paths of your directories are accessible to the crawlers. You can mention the paths inside robots.txt which you don't want the search engines to index. Read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en).
You can use your web server(e.g Apache, Ngnix) to render this file.